# Ubuntu 14.04 won't boot or shut down normally

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04

Here's the story:

I've upgraded from 12.04 (running alongside a Windows 7) to 14.04 from a DVD. I told it to **delete the previous version** completely, so it was technicaly a fresh install rather than an upgrade.

Everything seemed to work fine after the installation, so I played around a little and broke my desktop with some odd Compiz settings. I had no idea how to fix it quickly, so I decided to simply install Ubuntu again (and again deleting the previous version completely).

The installation ran through fine, but when it came to the reboot after the last step, I landed on a GRUB console:

```
                    GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB 
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible 
device or file completions

grub> _
```

Oh well... After asking Google I assumed that this means that the bootloader doesn't know what to load.

So I entered the boot device selection on startup and saw this:

[image: Boot device selecting screen]

**If I select "Internal HDD" in the Boot Manager, everything works fine** - I get the purple GRUB screen and it even shows me my Windows 7. But having to call the boot manager on each start is not quite a solution.

So, wondering where the 2 Ubuntu entries came from, I took a look at the boot menu in the BIOS and found this:

[image: BIOS Boot Menu]

So as far as I understand it has something to do with GRUB and UEFI, but I don't know enough about any of it to put it all together...

So my question is: 
What's wrong here and how can I fix this?

When I shut down Ubuntu, it hangs on the purple screen, with the dots blinking, but even after 10 minutes nothing happens, so I have to switch it off. Rebooting works as expected, though.

Does it have something to do with the problem above?

Comment: What happens when you disable `UEFI Boot`?

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen Yep... That makes everything work as expected (even the shutdown!) :) But I don't quite understand why? What's wrong with UEFI? It was enabled before, why wouldn't it work now?

Comment: I had the same problem, every cold boot would get me in GRUB rescue, until I re-ordered the boot order. Disabling Fast Boot solved this problem for me. Could you try if this works for you too?

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen The EFI entries are separate from the other ones, so I actually can't change the order, I just can disable UEFI and then it falls back to the 'normal' ones, and they already are in the right order. But I can't put any of them *before* UEFI while it's enabled. So I guess I'll just have to deal with the no-UEFI-thing... But I think that shouldn't be too big of a problem :) Please feel free to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `UEFI Boot` to disabled to use legacy booting.

If you want to use UEFI you can try to disable `Fast Boot`, this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update and install grub freshly. Open the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub
```

and this will install grub automatically to the required drives.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the right approach, grub isn't actually 'broken', I even see the right entries in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and everything works fine if I select a non-efi boot device.

Comment: @Quasdunk Because I have got that black grub console screen once when I was messing up with windows installation alongside Ubuntu and installing the grub again made it normal.

Comment: @Quasdunk Moreover you could give it a try!

Comment: Ok, I gave it a shot, but still got the same results... Thanks anyway for your help!